# How we can change label of Button to Bold or italic?

Tags: swiftui

I got this Button Which I Like change label of it to Bold or Italic, I know it is easy with defining Text, but I want to know how we can do this without Text?

```
Button("Tap me!") { print("Hello, World!") }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `init(action:label:)`? The init you're using now is for cases when you don't need to edit style of the label.

Comment: can you explain more or sample code? As We know Text has access to .bold, but Button has not! I am trying to bypass this problem with using .font of Button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do any styling with custom button style, like below:

```
Button("Tap me!") { print("Hello, World!") }
    .buttonStyle(BoldButtonStyle())
```

and custom style

```
struct BoldButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label.font(Font.body.bold())
    }
}
```

In similar way you can add colors, hightlight, etc.

**Updated:** if it is only font, then just

```
Button("Tap me!") { print("Hello, World!") }
   .font(Font.body.bold())
```

Comment: I know this way, it is over kill for what I wanted, could we just reach same result, just using .font ?

Comment: That is what I wanted, the Updated one. I use your first code for some shadow or animation but not for easy font things. thanks